# Testing various versions of iPhone Safari

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, safari, mobile-safari

I am developing a jquerymobile App, and things are looking good in IOS5 with the most up-to-date version of Safari, I really need to test some older versions of Safari and its Webkit to ensure things are looking good for most browser versions.

I realise I can fire up an old version of xcode with SDK4 , and test IOS4, but what I really need to test is the various versions of Safari, does anyone know how to do this? I'm assuming it is possible to upgrade Safari without upgrading your IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the version of Safari that comes with the OS (on stock iOS devices).  Also, the iOS Simulator on a Mac does not produce an exact representation of the functionality of Safari on an iOS device, especially older versions.

The only way to accurately test for compatibility and functionality is to buy, beg or borrow an old iDevice that has not be updated to newer OS version (and thus Safari version) past the version you want to test.

Comment: Hi hotpaw2, wow ok thank you for that really informative. I've been reading that IOS3 and lower only have around a 5% marketshare, so in effect I only need to test with my own IOS5 device, and then run the IOS 4 emulator (any 4.X version, as I presume the safari version was not updated during any 4.X OS updates) And then that has me pretty much covered...... am I right?